# How ABP framework design its folder structure when it comes to extending an existing module/feature with another module?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

I want to know how Abp decides its framework folder structure when it comes to extending an existing module/feature with another module. Honestly, I have little confusion with it. Let me explain it with an example of ObjectExtending and Uow modules/features.

When extending the ObjectExtending Module with the AspNetCore Module, the extension codes are located under Volo/Abp/**ObjectExtending** folder. However, when extending the Uow Module with the AspNetCore Module, the extension codes are located under Volo/Abp/**AspNetCore/ObjectExtending** folder.

Why both extension codes are not in the **AspNetCore** folder or not in their own folders(e.g. Volo/**Abp/ObjectExtending** and Volo/**Abp/Uow**)?

What is the difference?

| ObjectExtending Module | Extending ObjectExtending Module with AspNetCore Module |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

| Uow Module | Extending Uow Module with AspNetCore Module |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |